# Can't read Excel 2010 xltm spreadsheet files programmatically

Tags: c#, excel-2010

I have some existing C# which reads *.xlsm spreadsheets into Excel 2010. When I save as the spreadsheet from within Excel 2010 to a xltm file selecting the format "Excel Macro-Enabled Template (*xltm) from the "save As" dialog.

The resultant file double clicks and launches in Excel. As it is a template you get a copy of the file as you should, everything works correctly.

If I try and load the xltm template file using code like:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

// blah....

Excel._Workbook workbook = _applicationHandle.Workbooks.Add(fullFilename);

// or 

 Excel._Workbook workbook = _applicationHandle.Workbooks._Open(fullFilename, misval, misval,
 misval, misval, misval, misval, misval, misval, misval, misval, misval, misval);
```

I get the following error:

```
Excel cannot open the file 'RiskStationCal.xltm' because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.
```

Maybe the Microsoft APIs can't read template spreadsheets?

Works for Xls and Xlsm files but not for XLTM files.

Comment: Are you using Exel interop library? That's a little old if I recall correctly. Since you are using Execl 2010 (or anything 2007+) have you tried using the open XML standard they introduced? You can use free libraries like EPPlus (http://epplus.codeplex.com/) or ClosedXml (http://closedxml.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Not when it's part of an Excel Add-in you can't....

Comment: Don't know if this helps, but in straight VBA you can add any type of file, e.g., `Workbooks.Add("myworkbook.xlsm")` will open a copy called "myworkbook1.xlsm".  Does that work for you?

Comment: That is what I'm doing exactly but from C#... but I get the error!?!

Comment: Works for Xls and Xlsm files.

Comment: So the hunch was right, but I don't know why doesn't work for .xltm.

Comment: try to play with security settings in your Excel application, not sure if it's gonna work or not, but i have no other ideas for now.

Comment: Tried same with 2007 Office - worked flawlessly, no exceptions or warnings.